# Having a JVM with Clojure running in the background

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to have a JVM with Clojure running in the background, which evaluates Clojure code on demand?

The goal is to write some small "scripts" in Clojure, something that one would do with a scripting language like bash for example.

There is a way to write "shebang-style" scripts with the boot building tool, however the execution takes way too long because of the JVM/Clojure startup-time.

Comment: Have a look at Planck: http://planck-repl.org/ It's specifically designed for that kind of thing. It's cljs instead of clj, but you still get a lot of bang for your shebang.

Comment: ah, too bad - I'm using linux..

Comment: Hmm, how about Drip? https://github.com/ninjudd/drip

Comment: this is not a solution, because it handles only the jvm. most of the startup time is caused by clojure itself since it's so big.

Answer (score 1):

Use [clojure.tools.nrepl](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl) to start a nREPL server that "runs in the background". Then you'll be able to run any "script" by attaching nREPL client to it.